# Typo in theorem about distance square function to a curve

Tags: differential-geometry

In the following let $\gamma: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^n$ be a smooth curve and let $u \in \mathbb R^n$. Define the distance square function $f_d:  I \to \mathbb R$ on $\gamma$ from $u$ as $f_d(t) = (\gamma(t) -u)\cdot(\gamma(t) - u)$.

This definition is followed by the following propositioin:

$\gamma$ has $k$-point contact for $t=t_0$ with the circle centred at $u$ passing through $\gamma (t_0)$ if and only if the distance square function $f_d$ on $\gamma$ from $u$ satisfies $f_d^{(i)}(t_0)=0$ for $i=1,\dots, k-1$ and $f_d^{(k)}(t_0) \neq 0$.

But I believe there are two  typos in this:

A point of contact should have zero distance from $\gamma$. So in particular, $f_d(t_0)=0$ (i.e. $i\in \{0, \dots, k-1\}$).

The second typo I suspect is:

$f_d$ measures the distance of $\gamma$ to $u$ so if a circle is centred at $u$ it would measure the distance to the centre of the circle. This is not the intention of the proposition though: points of contact lie on the circle not in its centre.

> Are these really typos or am I misunderstanding the theorem?

Comment: This can be found for example [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=rhq3YCguBOUC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) on page 22.

Comment: You're misunderstanding. I think the statement is correct. $f_d(t_0)$ must be equal to the radius of the touching circle, not equal to zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As bubba said, you misunderstood.

> A point of contact should have zero distance from $\gamma$.

True. But $f_d$ is distance from point $u$, not from $\gamma$.  At the point where $\gamma$ has $k$-point contact with circle of radius $r$ centered at $u$, the function $f_d$ is equal to $r$.

Similarly  with the second concern. The points of contact lie on the circle, but the distance under consideration is the distance to the center of the circle.